# ffmpeg undefined symbol av_frame_alloc

Tags: c, ffmpeg

So i have been trying to use the ffmpeg api's in my c project. So i first looked at some examples on the ffmpeg website and i have been trying to compile one of the examples. Im getting

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_av_frame_alloc", referenced from:
    _audio_decode in ccd4jpMz.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I looked at the documentation on ffmpegs website and it says av_frame_alloc is a part of libavutil
so when i linked libavutil i got the same error. I tried linking all the libraries, i tried different orders of the libraries because i read that makes a difference. As of now I am lost and starting to lose it, any help would be appreciated. This is what i have been trying to compile the example.

```
    gcc -o test /Users/NahNig/Desktop/CPrograms/AudioDecoder.c $(pkg-config --libs
    --cflags libavutil libavformat libavcodec)
```

Comment: How old is your libavutil? av_frame_alloc was added about 8 months ago, so you may just need to update.

Comment: I think that is it, i am going to check if it does work but the version I am using is 1.2.4 and it looks like the latest is 2.1. So i guess Homebrew is very behind when it comes to ffmpeg. Is there a way to upgrade ffmepg directly or should i just build it from the source?

Comment: FFmpeg's API changes fairly regularly so unless you're targeting a specific version for distribution it's a good idea to stay up to date. FFmpeg is primarily developed with the intent of being built from top-of-tree. Check the comments about development vs release versions on http://ffmpeg.org/download.html There's also a link there to static builds for OS X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FFmpeg: undefined references to av\_frame\_alloc()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057248/ffmpeg-undefined-references-to-av-frame-alloc)